# The TFS collection (http://xxxxx:8080/tfs/tfs_xxxdefaultcollection) does not exist in the Release Management Server

Tags: .net, deployment, tfs, release

Here is my setup"

- TFS version – 2015
- Release Management – 2015
- Visual Studio- 2012

*Account* - All are running under a same service account and the same account is configured as a release manager in RM client.

*Domain* - all servers are in same domain

*Servers* – TFS , RM server and RM client are in same box. The deployment agent is in application server under same domain.

*Process template* - As I am triggering the build from VZ-2012 I am using `DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml`

**What is working**

I have queue a build from VS Studio and its working as expected
I can deploy that package from release management client to its destination.

**What is not working –**

When ever I set the release (in process template) to true I am getting the following error

```
Release the Build

00:03
Copy Files to Drop Location

00:00
Run the Release Management Build process for the Current Configuration

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Build starting process...
Processing using the following parameters:
TeamFoundationServerUrl:                http://xxxx:8080/tfs/tfs_xxxcdefaultcollection
TeamProjectName:                        xxxxx
TeamProjectWithCollection:              tfs_xxxdefaultcollection/xxxxx
BuildDefinitionName:                    Generic_Voice_Build_web_portals_XX
BuildNumber:                            Generic_Voice_Build_web_portals_XX_20161003063809.1
TargetStage:

Creating the release and waiting for deployment result...

ERROR: The TFS collection (http://xxx:8080/tfs/tfs_xxxdefaultcollection) does not exist in the Release Management Server.
Exit: 1

00:00
If Release Build Error Occurs

00:00
Throw Release Build Failed Exception
```

Tried all the possible fix available, no luck. Please help.

Comment: Have you checked if your "TeamFoundationServerUrl" is registered on your RM deploy agent (on Administration > Manage TFS)? This trick worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The template you should use for TFS 2015 is as below:

- TFVC: ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml.
- Git: ReleaseGitTemplate.12.xaml

Also, please follow the below screenshot to add your TFS collection in RM Client, and click **Verify** successfully.

[image]

> Instead of setting RM server and RM client, Release Management
>   features have been integrated into **Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015
>   Update 2 and above**, and into the **Release** hub in TFS web access.
>   The newer web-based version is the recommended, we encourage you to
>   use the web-based version in TFS 2015 Update 2 and above. More
>   details, check:
>   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/overview.